# Are COM objects dynamic or static

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, com

I am trying to make a sort of proxy, and I am wondering whether COM methods and properties are static or dynamic. In other words, does .NET call the com object and tell it which method it wants executed, and then lets the com object pretend it has executed it (the way DynamicObject lets you do in .NET, just return true for TryInvokeMember without doing anything), or does .NET actually go and call the COM method directly (static)?

Comment: Can you please clarify "com object pretend it has executed it (dynamic),"?

Comment: @Alexei: He's asking whether the method binding is done by the compiler (statically bound), or whether the object itself resolves the binding - just like with [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)/[`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx) which can pretend to have any method.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking the difference between *early binding* (static) and *late binding* (dynamic).  C# supports both.

Early binding requires you create an Interop assembly using a tool like [TlbImp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx) to generate a proxy to the COM object, which calls the interface methods directly.

To use late binding you can use either reflection (messy) or the `dynamic` keyword to bind the method calls at run-time.

However, the COM object will not "pretend" it executed a method you ask for - if the method does not exist, you will get a run-time exception.

Comment: Would `Activator.CreateInstance` be late binding? Could the COM object pretend the method existed if it wanted too? Or does .NET somehow make it do stuff?

Comment: If you call methods by their string names, then yes, that would be late-binding.  Could a COM object ignore calls to missing methods? Not one created in C#.  You'd have to implement IDispatch manually in C++ which would be a pain.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make a DynamicObject COM object, but by now I can tell I'm barking up the wrong tree. I don't know a whole lot about COM either, so I am trying to figure it out as well. I'm going to ask in another question.

Comment: Well you could certainly wrap a COM wrapper in a `DynamicObject`, try to call the methods using late binding, and do nothing if it fails, but I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a proxy that uses reflection and `DynamicObject`. I basically have it working, but for my use case, it also has to be able to be called from COM. Or whatever the correct term is.